# Delphi Tooltip Symbol Insight / Code Insight Stopped Working

Tags: delphi, tooltip, source-insight, insight

I'm running Delphi Tokyo 10.2. My Tooltip Symbol Insight (when debugging) has suddenly stopped working. The Code Insight that shows tool-tip information in the editor on mouse hover has also stopped working. All other Code Insight features appear to be working.

I attempted a Windows Update (Windows 11) which failed and rolled back. (I don't know if it's related to that or not. Code Insight worked before the update attempt and now doesn't.)

I have unchecked and rechecked all the Code Insight check-boxes in the Options window. In my frustration I have even uninstalled and reinstalled Delphi 10.2. Still no Tooltip Code Insight.

I'm guessing that it may be an invalid or missing registry entry but really have no idea.

Does anyone have the experience or knowledge to get my tool tip code insight back?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with a totally new project?

Comment: Just tried a brand new project now. Still no Code Insight tool tips in either edit mode or debugging.

Comment: Copy the Delphi shortcut into a new file (e.g., DelphiTest). Edit that new shortcut, and add `-rFoo` to the end of the command line. Double-click the shortcut to start the IDE, which will load in the default mode with none of your third-party applications or IDE preferences loaded. Start a new project and see if the problem goes away. If so, your registry entries got fouled up with the failed Windows update. You can export the registry entries from the Foo personality using RegEdit, change the key location and then import it back into the registry.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I admire your depth of knowledge but this, unfortunately, did not work. It did create a new environment but the tool-tips were still not present. A check of [Tools | Options | Code Insight] in the new environment indicated they should have been available. I also checked [Tools | Options | Editor Options | Use Syntax Highlight] which, as I recall, may also affect this feature. Does Delphi call any Windows or .Net routines for tool-tip functionality? Maybe something there has been corrupted.

Comment: By the way, the tool tips also DO NOT appear when hovering over a component in the Design Editor. (Though tapping the Alt key can make tooltips work for the selected component and some, but not all, other components.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those Delphi developers that may experience this in the future, I have found the answer.

My setup is on a laptop that usually has multiple monitors. I removed the additional monitors and was able to successfully install the Windows 11 update. The issue then resolved to the following:

- Run the laptop with no extra monitors and Delphi tooltips worked
- Add a monitor and Delphi tooltips stopped working

The same was true of the applications I built in Delphi. If I ran them on the laptop with no extra monitors I got tooltips. If I added a monitor the tooltips disappeared.

It turns out that I installed ElevenClock (a Windows app that adds seconds to the clock in the system tray - an extremely valuable feature for me) at around the same time that I attempted the Windows 11 update.

I removed ElevenClock and, presto, my tooltips now work flawlessly. Those with more knowledge of Windows messaging are free to add comments but it would appear that ElevenClock was intercepting the message that ultimately generated the Delphi Application.OnShowHint event.

Comment: That worked, I always use second screen in my laptop latest 6 month and I didn't realize that debug tooltip gone since when I using second monitor. 
I just trying using PC screen only (hdmi cable still connected to second monitor) and debug tooltip appear again, but when I switch to second screen again it still appear. Thanks man !!